# How to configure the plugin org.apache.cordova.file-trasfer in index.js?

Tags: apache, cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am creating project  in which i added the plugin org.apache.cordova.file-trasfer into that i need  to configure in index.js.Suggest me an example or idea

Comment: can you please be clear ?   You want to use that file-transfer's functionality in index.js ??

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added FileTransfer plugin then you can create FileTransfer object in index.js like

var fileURL = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file.txt";
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);

Refer [FileTransfer doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md) for different API example

Note: Refer [Manage Plugins documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757051.aspx) on how to add plugins through config.xml in Visual Studio.